# How to tag a question about a specific command

Tags: discussion, tagging

if appropriate, should we tag questions with the name of the relevant command (eqnarray, align) as well as the general topic (equations) ?

Comment: The title of this question is a bit misleading, because this question is about a subset of the tagging protocols on this site. Could you please edit it to something like 'How to tag a question about a specific command?' and retag it with 'tagging' tag?

Answer (score 5):

I'd say yes, when there's a particular command that the question is actually about, rather than the principle or the kind of output. If a particular command only appears in an answer, even the accepted answer, I'd still be hesitant to tag the question with it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not convinced that this would be useful tag information.  I would be surprised if there was anyone who *specifically* sought out questions on a particular command to answer (one use of tags is help people easily find questions that they might be able to answer).  Similarly, anyone looking to see if someone's asked a question on a particular command before is far more likely to search for it than to look through the tags.

Of course, if there is a major command that attracts a lot of questions then I can see it might be appropriate (say, `\def`, but even then I'd tag it "macros" since I see no reason to differentiate *by tags* between questions about `\def`, `\edef`, `\gdef`, `\xdef` and so forth).

For any tag, the question has to be "Does this tag add anything to the question?".  The key there is "add": if there's an obvious keyword already in the question, then the argument for having as a tag is weakened.

I must confess that I'm not a great user of tags, but what I find them useful for is to help decide whether or not a question is worth reading.  On MathOverflow, if the title looks interesting but the tag says "algebraic-geometry" then I know that there's no point looking at it.  On the other hand, if the title looks obscure but the tag says "differential-geometry" then I still take a look just in case the real question is more interesting than the title suggested.